# How to set a surge.sh email

Tags: surge.sh

I'm doing personal development and trying to use surge.sh to deploy the project. This one is a training exercise so I want to use my personal email address instead of my work email.

My work mail is globally set in `~/.gitconfig`. I also have surge installed globally.
`surge --version` prints out `v0.21.3`.

After building the project and running command `surge` in public folder I get

```
Running as my.name@workaddress.fi

        project: /Users/myAccount/Documents/personal/project/public/
```

on my shell without any option for setting the email. Surge skips the email and prompts only the option to set the project path. The tutorial that I'm following has the option to set email before project path. So does their own [getting-started-with-surge -intro.](https://surge.sh/help/getting-started-with-surge)

Figured out this could have something to do with the global `~/.gitconfig` settings. I set the email for this one specific repository to my personal address but no luck.

Anyone else out there having the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have created an account with this email and surge is using this email. So you can change this email address. Otherwise you can see your account credentials with the following command:

```
surge whoami
```

My last suggestion would be to change the collaborator emails mit `surge --add <new_mail>` and `surge --remove <old_mail>`.

Comment: `surge whoami` prints out working email. Trying out `surge --add <new_mail>` or `surge --remove <old_mail>` both prompts the same

```
Running as my.name@workaddress.fi

        project: /Users/myAccount/Documents/personal/project/public/
```
as before. If there's no other solution for this maybe will try to setup surge.sh first with the initially set work email and try removing it afterwards.

Comment: So I think you use an account with your working email address. Maybe you can logout with the command `surge logout` and create another account with your private email address.

Comment: Ah, splendid! `surge logout` worked. I guess there was some automagic going on behind the curtains and surge grabs the default address from somewhere (git. etc). This was the first time I was using it right after installation. 

But never mind that, now I can move on! Thanks!